# Drool Global Variable Initialization in drl file

Tags: java, drools, kie

```
 package com.example.drools; 

 global Integer count; // I want to initialize this count variable with some 
                         default value. 

   rule "Initialize"
   when
   then
       count= 1; // Locally it's possible but want it to set globally which can 
                     be use in any other rules just simply by calling it.
       System.out.println("count="+count);
   end

  rule "Drools Introduction"
  when
  then
     System.out.println("count="+count); // Here output is coming null which in 
                                            want some default value set for 
                                            global value.
  end
```

So Want to Initialize Count variable in drl file only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you update a global from inside a rule is by using the automagic variable `kcontext`:

```
global Integer count;

rule "Initialize"
salience 100
when
then
       kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("count", 1);
end
```

Some notes:

- You should use a high salience in your rule so it gets executed before any other rule that is also using the global.
- This method will not work if you are using the global in the LHS of your rules. If that's the case I would suggest to use a Fact instead of a global.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Esteban Aliverti@ It's seems working do we have any other approach then this.

Comment: Java code before you insert your facts and fire your rules.

Answer (score 0):

### Java Code

```
   public void loanApplication(LoanApplication loanApplication) {

        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        kieSession.insert(loanApplication);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
// get your variable from .drl file

        kieSession.getGlobal("myString");


    }
```

### `.drl` file

```
import com.example.demo.LoanApplication
global java.lang.String myString;
rule "Approval rule"
when
    $loanApplication : LoanApplication()
    LoanApplication(creditScore >= 600, income >= 30000, debtToIncomeRatio <= 50, employmentStatus != EmploymentStatus.UNEMPLOYED)
then
    System.out.println("Loan application approved!");

     kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("myString", "Loan application approved!");
    $loanApplication.setLoan(true);
    update($loanApplication);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer and welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve your answer, please include some text about how your answer works.

Comment: This does not answer the question. They want to know how to default the global value in the DRL. Your code doesn't do that and is borderline entirely irrelevant.